# Legend Alignment using Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, bar-chart, fxml, scenebuilder, java-11

Recently, I used the scene builder to draw a bar chart; however, the legend is not aligned correctly. When I use

```
barchart.setLegendSide(Side.BOTTOM);
```

the legend shows vertically as in the picture below while I wanted it to be shown horizontally.

[image: Bar Chart]

Despite that, if I don't use the scene builder, there is no problem with the chart. Please show me the way to fix this issue.

**Main file**

```
package LinkedIn;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
    
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/LinkedIn/barchart.fxml"));
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("LinkedIn");
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

**FXML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>

<BarChart fx:id="barchart" animated="false" barGap="10.0" categoryGap="20.0" title="Car Sales by Brands" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LinkedIn.Controller">
   <xAxis>
      <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" fx:id="xAxis" />
   </xAxis>
   <yAxis>
      <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis" side="LEFT" />
   </yAxis>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="25.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
   </padding>
</BarChart>
```

**Controller File**

```
package LinkedIn;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Controller implements Initializable{
    
    @FXML
    private BarChart<String, Number> barchart;
    
    @FXML
    CategoryAxis xAxis;
    
    @FXML
    NumberAxis yAxis;
    
    void loadData() {
        xAxis.setLabel("Brand");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        
        XYChart.Series<String, Number>  series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series1.setName("Bob");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Toyota", 200));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Ford", 300));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Jaguar", 50));
        
        XYChart.Series<String, Number>  series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        series2.setName("Peter");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Toyota", 500));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Ford", 150));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("Jaguar", 100));
       
        
        barchart.getData().add(series1);
        barchart.getData().add(series2);
        barchart.setLegendSide(Side.BOTTOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        loadData();
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: I think that has more to do with the width. What happens when you expand your scene's width?

Comment: Hi @Sedrick, as the code above. I don't think there are any issues with the width of the legend. And, if I expand the width, the problem is still the same as above.